# Why gradle 7.3 is incapable of finding a submodule defined using relative path?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-submodule

I have a gradle project with 1 submodule, defined in the following file structure (+- refers to a directory):

```
+- <root>
  build.gradle.kts
  +- graph-commons
    +- core
      build.gradle.kts
```

The only submodule was included using the following kotlin script:

```
val graphCommons = project(File("./graph-commons/core"))

includeBuild(graphCommons)
```

When I execute ./gradlew clean assembly, I got the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/home/peng/git/shapesafe/settings.gradle.kts' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Project with path './graph-commons/core' could not be found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 492ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/home/peng/git/shapesafe/settings.gradle.kts' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Project with path './graph-commons/core' could not be found.
```

What went wrong? Why the valid path "./graph-commons/core" cannot be identified by gradle?

The project is uploaded and tested on github:

https://github.com/tribbloid/shapesafe/runs/4280805005?check_suite_focus=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle does not work this way. A project path refers to a gradle project path, not to a file path. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#multi_project_builds

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, the [`project(File)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#project-java.io.File-) method that is available in the `settings.gradle.kts` is a special method allowing to receive a [`ProjectDescriptor`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html) whose directory points to the given file. The project must be present already e.g. by including it via [`include(String...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#include-java.lang.String...-) first.

I first thought you tried to use the [`DependencyHandler#project(Map)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#project-java.util.Map-) method in some way, which is the usual way to refer to project dependencies. Gradle separates between dependencies and multi-project setup. In the `settings.gradle.kts` you usually setup the project structure while you declare dependencies in each `build.gradle.kts`. When using `includeBuild` you merely depend on the build of another completely separate project. When you then want to declare a dependency to a project from that included build you usually use the project's artifact coordinates to do so. This way the build still works when removing the `includeBuild` declaration.

If you want to use composite builds see here for basic usage: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_composite_builds_basics.html
You will have to coordinate the artifact publishing and corresponding dependencies to make it work like a normal multi-project. Something like this:

```
graph-commons
|build.gradle.kts -> group = "org.scala-lang"; version = "1.0";
|settings.gradle.kts -> include(":graph-commons-core")
|graph-commons-core
||build.gradle.kts

shapesafe
|settings.gradle.kts -> includeBuild("../graph-commons")
|core
||build.gradle.kts -> dependencies { implementation("org.scala-lang:graph-commons-core:1.0") }
```

Comment: The argument for that function is a "File" type, sounds like a design flaw if it is the case

Comment: Ah, now I see what you did there. The project method in context of the settings returns an already included project existing in the given directory (https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#project-java.io.File-).

Comment: You have to include the project via include (multi-project build) or make it a separate gradle build and include it via includeBuild (composite build feature).

Comment: I've tried `include(":graph-commons:core")` but got other errors, which are caused by the fact that `:graph-commons` is a project that I DO NOT want to include, it is in conflict in many ways with the main project

Comment: So the actual problem is: How to include ":graph-commons:core" but NOT ":graph-commons"?

Comment: Ok, I see. You will have to decide, if you want to keep graph-commons as a separate multi-project with its own build or integrate it in to your other multi-project. In what way is there a conflict? Dependency-wise projects are independent to each other as long as they don't depend on each other or you use some kind of BOM logic.

Comment: If you want to keep it separate, you should create an independent multi-project for graph-commons and include its build in your other project. See my answer for an example. I guess it's also ok to use a git submodule for this purpose and point to it via `includeBuild('./graph-commons')`  from your main build.

Comment: Unfortunately ":graph-commons" defines a different Scala version, it will totally cause the error if included. That version is mandated by CI & other projects, so it cannot be changed

Comment: Ok, when you really want to "plugin" a project like including the sources only, you may be able to do something like this, in `settings.gradle.kts`:
`include("graph-commons-core")`
`project(":graph-commons-core').projectDir = file("graph-commons/core")`

Comment: Nice. Compile successfully, rewarding now :)